# Saving entities with foreign key in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-ctp5, modelstate

I need some help doing something I am assuming is simple. I am using ASP.net MVC 3 with CodeFirst (CTP5)

I have two entities: Company and Location. A Company can many Locations. The classes are as follows (stripped of all needless info)

```
public class Company
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

}
```

Now in my controller, I only allow creating a Location within the context of a Company, so the Company Id is always passed in (In the View, I show the name of the Company in a read only field, but do not allow the user to change/edit that.

```
    public ActionResult Create(int companyId)
    {
        Company company = _session.Single<Company>(c => c.Id == companyId);
        Location newLocation = new Location {Company = company};
        return View(newLocation);
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Location location)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _session.Add<Location>(location);
            _session.CommitChanges();                
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        } else {
            return View(location);
        }
    }
```

Now whenever I try to create a new location, the ModelState.IsValid is always false due to the fact that location.Company.Name is not supplied and is a required field on Company. I am never trying to create a new company here, I merely trying to create a location with a reference to the correct company. I don't want to add the Name property to the view just to get the ModelState to validate. How can this be accomplished easily? Should I be passing something different from the view? or to the view?

Comment: on your Create(Location) function does location.CompanyID have a value set?  Maybe you need to define
public int CompanyID { get; set; }

Comment: yea, the company Id is set (proved this by checking out the ModelState when saving. The only error showing is the Name field being required on the Company

Comment: I was able to get this working using what I still think is a kludge, but it works well and should be easy enough to change if I can track down a better way of doing it. Basically I have done two things. see below post aas i dont have enough space to put htis in a comment) lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i was explaining in my comment, i stumbled upon a small change which makes this work, still think it is a kludge as I dont see why i need to duplicate the child Id paramater, but the best/simplest one I could find that should be easy to update in the future and I will be the first to admit I dont know all (or most) of what there is in CodeFirst.

I changed the location class from:

```
public class Location  
{      
    public int Id { get; set; }        

    [Required]      
    public string Name { get; set; }        

    [Required]      
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }    
}
```

To:

```
public class Location  
{      
    public int Id { get; set; }        

    [Required]      
    public string Name { get; set; }        

    [Required]      
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }    
}
```

Now as far as I can tell, this hasnt changed the database schema at all, but now the only thing which is required on the Location (when validating) is that there is an ID in the CompanyId field, the Company property can be left null (before, it was trying to validate a proper Company since the Company class was required).

So now when creating a Location, the only thing the view needs to pass back in the CompanyId.

Anyone see any drawbacks? or a better way?

Comment: This looks good to me,  there is also a [SkipRequestValidation] anotation you may be able to use

Comment: Thanks Deveo. Ill look into that as well.

Comment: @Peter - doesn't seem like a kludge to me; this seems like the bone fide solution.  I have spent the past day or so trying to get my head round this, and your posts here have managed to wrap it for me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily just add a **hidden field** with company name on your `form`. Its data will get picked up and sent to your POST action as expected.

If you don't use company name on the server side at all, you can fill this hidden field up with any dummy text as long as company ID is correct (because you use it). But if you do need correct company name with your ID, you'll have to fill actual name into hidden field instead of some dummy text.

Anyway. This will add a hidden field for your company name

```
<%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Company.Name) %>
```

and if you don't have your Company property set to anything then, you can as well use this:

```
<%= Html.Hidden("Company.Name", "Super duper company") %>
```

Whether this value is an actual name or a dummy name it doesn't really matter. Your model will be valid upon postback.

### Regular postback or Ajax?

I suppose you're using a regular postback and not an Ajax postback. If you do use Ajax one and you're using jQuery and calling `$.post()` or `$.ajax()` or something similar, you can always provide whatever object you like. You can fill any value for the company name in your JavaScript code.

If you have complex objects in JavaScript and would like to send them to your controller action with strong type parameters (so they will be validated) you can use [this little jQuery plugin](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html) of mine, that prepares any JSON object to be correctly sent to Asp.net MVC action so data will be automatically data bound to your strong types to get validated. Does JavaScript dates as well. :)

### Additional information

Since you pointed out (in a comment) that your entities are very much work in progress and you may be adding/removing required fields, this may be very tedious to also change all related views.

Yet there are ways you may take, to make your life a bit easier when it comes to changable models and different validation scenarios depending on object state:

1. Have separate view models for creation process that also include functionality to auto-convert to application model class:

   ```
   public class LocationCreate
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public int CompanyId { get; set; }

       public Location ToModelInstance()
       {
           return new Location {
               Id = this.Id,
               Name = this.Name,
               Company = new Company {
                   Id = this.CompanyId,
                   Name = "Super duper company Ltd." // you can as well omit this line
               }
           };
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use inheritance:

   ```
   public class CompanyBase
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
   }

   public class Company : CompanyBase
   {
       [Required]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
   }

   public class Location
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public virtual CompanyBase Company { get; set; }

   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, yea i thought of that, but right now i only have the two required fields as I am setting up alot of the scaffolding for my site, but everytime I add a new required field to my Company entity, I will need to come back and edit the Location Create method/views. Seems like there should be some way of decoupling the two since all I really need is the id.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - nice plugin, but it's worthwhile mentioning ASP.NET MVC 3 includes JSON model binding by default (JsonValueProviderFactory)

Comment: @Peter: Check my edited answer. Depending on your application model entities and their usage, scenario 2 may be a bit more cumbersome and complicated.

Comment: @RPM1984: That's right but it's not added by default afaik. You have to manually add it in the global.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I will take a look more when i get home :). When I said my models will be changing, what I meant was that as I change my Company model (adding new fields, some of which will be required), that should have no bearing on creating a Location, since all the location should care about is the Id. If I added a mandatory address field, then obviously I would have to update the Company view, but I would like to be able to leave the location view and controllers alone :). Again thanks for the info, I will take a look into your approaches and see if I can adopt one :)

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - no, you don't. :) I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application right now, i did a jquery post to an action method with a strongly typed object parameter, and it automatically binded correctly, as long as the name of the JSON properties match the model.

Comment: @RPM1984: If you did something like `$.ajax({ data: {Id: 1, Name: "Test"}, ... });` then this is not being picked up by that particular value provider factory. You have to actually send JSON string. Just making sure your test is relevant. But... Beware. If you do send JSON strings that means you're already using some javascript library. This makes it actually equivalent. You have to use some added JS functionality to make it work. Either my simple plugin or a more complex JSON library (granted JSON stringification will get wide support *soon*).

Comment: Your right, im using the MsAjax library. One liner - `Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(jsonObject)`. Then i stuff that in the `data` property of the `$.ajax` object.